# Normalizing data from a pair of CSV tables

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I'm trying to normalize some data, and can't seem to come up with a solution. What I have is a table like this:

```
weight  position1   position2   position3
1       10          20          30
2       25          35          45
3       17          05          22
```

and one like this:

```
location    position
6           1   
7           1   
8           2   
9           2   
10          2   
11          3   
12          3
```

How do I normalize the above so that given a location and a weight, I can find the value for a given position?

I can use Perl, Python, Excel, MySQL or pretty much any tool on the block to do the actual reshuffling of the data; where I'm having a problem is in coming up with a reasonable schema.

---

The desired outcome here is something like

```
if location == 11 -> position is 3
```

therefore,

```
if weight == 2 -> the value is 45
```

Comment: Where/What is the relation between position and the rest of the data?

Comment: Creating the relationship would be part of the normalization, right? The desired outcome here is something like `if location == 11, then position is 3; therefore, if weight == 2, the value is 45`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing to do is "unpivot" your first table to this:

```
weight  position     value
   1        1          10
   1        2          20
   1        3          30
   2        1          25
   2        2          35
   2        3          45
   3        1          17
   3        2          05
   3        3          22
```

The first two columns should contain unique pairs of values. If you have other information that only depends on weight, you would need another table for that. Same for positions.

#### Converting to the new model

If you already have the tables, then you can create the first table (t1) with this statement:

```
create table t1_new
select weight, 1 as position, position1 as value
from   t1
union all
select weight, 2 as position, position2 as value
from   t1
union all
select weight, 3 as position, position3 as value
from   t1
```

Then, after verification of the result, drop t1, and rename t1_new to t1.

#### Querying from the new model

To query from these tables the value for a given location and weight, you should use a join:

```
select     value
from       t1
inner join t2 on t2.weight = t1.weight
where      t2.location = 11
and        t1.position = 3
```

Comment: Thanks... that's the reluctant conclusion I was coming to. The tables are actually ~1500 x 150 entries, so I _really_ wanted to avoid producing a Cartesian product of all that - but it looks like I'll have to.

This could be done with PHP and MySQL - e.g., `$pos = mysql_query('SELECT position FROM t1 WHERE location = "X"'); $val = mysql_query('SELECT position' . $pos . ' FROM t2 WHERE weight = "Y");`, but this is... less than graceful.

Comment: You're welcome. I added some stuff to my answer which may give some ideas to tackle this.